# If $|f_n|\leq g \in L^1$, and $f_n\rightarrow f$ in measure, then $f_n \rightarrow f \in L^1$ (Folland chp 2 ex. 34)

Tags: real-analysis, integration, analysis, measure-theory

In Folland's Real Analysis, 1999 2nd edition. So the precise statement is actually:

Let $(X, M, \mu)$ be a measure space. If $|f_n|\leq g \in L^1$, and $f_n\rightarrow f$ in measure, then  (1)$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \int f_n = \int f$ and (2)$f_n \rightarrow f \in L^1$, however unless I am seriously mistaken 2 implies 1...

So I have attempted to solve this problem and I am stuck, and want to ask for some help. My approach is contradiction. I will detail the work I have so far. I would prefer help which builds on my current work, however if my approach is futile then of course starting over is preferable, but in the end how you help is up to you.

Suppose that $f_n \rightarrow f$ in $L^1$ does not hold, then $\exists\; \epsilon > 0$ s.t. $\forall$ $N$, $\exists$ $n\geq N$ s.t. $\int_P |f_n -f| \geq \epsilon $ (where $P$ is a set of positive measure).

Now, we know that $f_n$ converges in measure, denote $\{x\;|\;|f_m(x)-f(x)|\geq \epsilon\}=F_{m,\epsilon}$, then $\exists$ M s.t. $\forall$ $m\geq M$, we have $\mu(F_{m,\epsilon})<\epsilon$.

Now, at this point I start to become unsure of what to do. THe most interesting thing I can come up with is this:

$$\sup_P |f_n -f| \mu(P)\geq \int_P |f_n-f| \geq \epsilon \mu(P) > 0$$

Also, we have that |f_n|\leq g, so we need to use this, but I am not sure how. Of course $\sup_P |f_n -f| \mu(P)\leq \sup_p 2g \mu(P)$ but I am not sure how this helps. Another interesting thing I found was that, $f_n \rightarrow f$ in $L^1$ is equivalent to $|f_n - f|\rightarrow 0$ in $L^1$, so if we could show that $\int_P |f_n-f|\rightarrow 0$ somehow, than perhaps this would say something close to "$f_n\rightarrow f$ in $L^1$"... (but I don't think it would say exactly that.

Thanks!

Comment: Hint: every subsequence $f_{n'}$ admits a subsequence $f_{n''}$ that converges a.e. to $f$.

Comment: Use the subsequence principle: $y_n \to y$ if and only if every subsequence of $(y_n)$ has a further subsequence that converges to $y$. Since convergence in measure implies a subsequence converges a.e., this reduces the problem to the case where $f_n \to f$ a.e., which is solved by the dominated convergence theorem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Let $(X, M, \mu)$ be a measure space. If $|f_n|\leq g \in L^1$, and $f_n\rightarrow f$ in measure, then:
>
> 1. $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \int f_n = \int f$ and
> 2. $f_n \rightarrow f \in L^1$.

You are right 2 implies 1. In fact, if $f_n \rightarrow f \in L^1$ then
$$\left | \int f_n - \int f \right | = \left | \int (f_n -  f) \right | \leq \int |f_n - f| \rightarrow 0. $$

Now, let us prove 1. We are going to prove by contradiction.

Suppose that $f_n \rightarrow f$ in $L^1$ does not hold, then there is $\varepsilon >0$ and a subsequence $\{f_{n_i}\}$ such that
$$\int |f_{n_i}-f | > \varepsilon \tag{1}$$
for all $i$.
However, $f_{n_i}\rightarrow f$ in measure, and so, from $\{f_{n_i}\}$, there is a subsequence $\{f_{n_{i_j}}\}$ that converges to $f$ a.e..  Since $f_{n_{i_j}} \rightarrow f$ a.e. and $|f_{n_{i_j}}|\leq g \in L^1$, by the Dominate Convergence theorem, we have that $f_{n_{i_j}} \rightarrow f$ in $L^1$. Contradiction to $(1)$. So, $f_n \rightarrow f$ in $L^1$.

Comment: Thank you for the help!